# Как вызвать default метод у интерфейса через рефлексию?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть ли возможность вызвать default метод через рефлексию в java 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот пример кода, который это делает

```
class A
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(InterfaceA.class.getMethod("defaultMethod").invoke((InterfaceA) () -> "Call some method"));
    }
}
interface InterfaceA
{
    default String defaultMethod()
    {
        return notDefaultMethod();
    }

    String notDefaultMethod();
}
```